# How to find outdated apps through the terminal?

Tags: command-line

Well I was going through  Ubuntu software and I saw that there are a few apps I must update, and that made me ask myself if there is a way to analyses my files for outdated things like the avast analysis on windows where all the outdated material is showed to you.

Comment: Just run `sudo apt-get upgrade`, and it'll list all the things that are out of date and upgrade them for you if you allow it to.

Comment: `ubuntu-support-status`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the command given below in the terminal to find the packages which can be upgraded :-

```
apt list --upgradable
```

It will list all the packages and apps that need to be upgraded.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have `synaptic` installed already, install it.

It will show you all the apps that need to be upgraded.